# React. Conditional Rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement

I have a React component:

```
class SignUpStepTwo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isTherapistUpdated: false,
      isProfessionalInfoAdded: false,
    }
  }

  render() {

    if (!this.state.isTherapistUpdated) {
      return (
        <StepTwoPersonalInfo />
      );
    }
    else if (this.state.isTherapistUpdated) {
      return (
        <StepTwoProfessionalInfo />
      );
    }
    else if (this.state.isProfessionalInfoAdded &&
      this.state.isTherapistUpdated) {
      return (
        <StepTwoTermsOfUse />
      );
    }
  }
}

export default SignUpStepTwo;
```

And I'm trying to change my bool flags and conditionally render my components.
But the last `if` is never satisfied and the `<StepTwoTermsOfUse/>` component is not rendered.

Comment: See also https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html - I particularly like **Inline If with Logical && Operator**

Comment: one of the first two ifs will always be true

Comment: I always make a statement of all conditions just to see if thats what I want.In your case, let `this.state.isTherapistUpdated` be `a` and `this.state.isProfessionalInfoAdded` be `b`. So, it would read as **If a does not exists, do this. If b exists, do that. But if a and b both exists, do something different**. Now if both `a` and `b` exists, 2nd condition automatically satisfies and it will not reach to 3rd condition. Try following style: **If a exists and b also exists, do something else. But if b doesn't exists, do that. And finally if a doesn't exists, do this**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the second condition is satisfied even if both this.state.isProfessionalInfoAdded and isTherapistUpdated are true.

To make this work you should put the third condition, before the second. Also, I've restructured your code a bit to skip unnecessary checks:

```
if (this.state.isProfessionalInfoAdded && this.state.isTherapistUpdated) {
  return (
      <StepTwoTermsOfUse/>
  );
}

if (this.state.isTherapistUpdated) {
  return (
      <StepTwoProfessionalInfo/>
  );
}

return (
    <StepTwoPersonalInfo />
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the last if in first & it should work !

Comment: Though its acceptable suggestion, its a comment and will attract unwanted comments/votes. My suggestion is to add some explanation as to what/why it would help? Are there any simpler approaches or alternatives

Answer (score 0):

You should switch your last two statements.
The second if statement in your question satisfies if the 3rd one satisfies as well. So the seconds one make the function exit.

```
class SignUpStepTwo extends Component {
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isTherapistUpdated: false,
            isProfessionalInfoAdded: false,
            }
        }
     }
render() {
        if (!this.state.isTherapistUpdated) {
            return (
                <StepTwoPersonalInfo />
            );
        }
        if (this.state.isProfessionalInfoAdded) {
            return (
                <StepTwoTermsOfUse/>
            );
        }

        return (
            <StepTwoProfessionalInfo/>
        );
    }
}

export default SignUpStepTwo;
```

What this does is:

- If `isTherapistIsUpdated === false`, then render `StepTwoPersonalInfo`
- If `isTherapistIsUpdate === true` (implied, because the first if does not match) AND `isProfessionalInfoAdded === true`, then render `StepTwoTermsOfUse`
- In any other case, which means `isTherapistIsUpdated === true` AND `isProfessionalInfoAdded === false`, render `StepTwoProfessionalInfo`

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use a temporary variable to set your logic result to, the code resuls being a bit clearer...

```
class SignUpStepTwo extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isTherapistUpdated: false,
            isProfessionalInfoAdded: false,
        }
    }

    render() {
        let render = (
          (!this.state.isTherapistUpdated) ? <StepTwoPersonalInfo /> :
          (this.state.isTherapistUpdated && this.state.isProfessionalInfoAdded) ? <StepTwoTermsOfUse/> :
          <StepTwoProfessionalInfo />
        );
        return render;
    }
}

export default SignUpStepTwo;
```